# Adding an MD5 Hash to my password Generator

Tags: php, hash, moodle

Trying to add an MD5 hash to my password generator for my custom moodle sign up script.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php 

    function randomPassword() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = Md5(rand(0, $alphaLength));
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}

    $PASSWORD = randomPassword();

    echo "First name:" . $_POST['firstname'] . "<br>"; 
    echo "Last name:" . $_POST['lastname'] . "<br>";    
    echo "Email:" . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";   
    echo "Password:" . $PASSWORD;
?>
```

Everytime I try it it doesn't seem to be hashed? Not sure how to test it but it doesnt SEEM to be hashing.

Any advice would be appreciate on how to test this

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: You are hashing a random number between 0 and 61, then use that hash as index to your alphabet array... What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @Quentin I don't think this really applies in this case.

Comment: By echoing user input directly out into HTML, you are making yourself [vulnerable to XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: @Quentin I'm echoing it at the moment to test the value returned

Comment: Hi Bradly - what is it that you are trying to do? What is the custom sign up script?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete that line:
`$n = Md5(rand(0, $alphaLength));`
and change next line to:
`$pass[] = $alphabet[rand(0, $alphaLength)];`. Works good - you get 8-chars random password.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a constructive answer. The other posts really believe I'd echo the information haha.

Comment: it's usually standard to leave it for a little while first

Comment: Little while later... ;-)